# Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client Invalid grant type for client

Tags: identityserver4

In my solution, I have 3 projects:

- Identity Server 4
- Web Client in ASP.NET Core 3.1
- Web Api in ASP.NET Core 3.1

So far I managed to get the `id token` from the web client but after adding another API project and tried to access API project which need authorization from Identity Server 4 to get `access token`, I got this error `Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client Invalid grant type for client` when I click login to Identity server. May I know how should I troubleshoot this error?

This is the current configuration in my `Startup` class which connects to Identity Server.

```
    private void SetOpenIdConnectOptions(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
        options.ClientId = "movie.web"; 
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("movie.api");
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ClientSecret = "xxx";
    }
```

I have tried to replace `options.ResponseType = "code id_token";` with `options.ResponseType = "code";` but still same error as above. That `xxx` is a test guid I generated using powershell.

And in my Identity Server `config.cs`:

```
public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            };


        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new ApiScope[]
            {
                new ApiScope("scope1"),
                new ApiScope("scope2"),
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
           new ApiResource[]
           {
                new ApiResource("movie.api", "The Movie API")
                {
                    Scopes = { "movie.api" }
                }
           };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[]
            {
                // m2m client credentials flow client
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "m2m.client",
                    ClientName = "Client Credentials Client",

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("511536EF-F270-4058-80CA-1C89C192F69A".Sha256()) },

                    AllowedScopes = { "scope1" }
                },

                // interactive client using code flow + pkce
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "interactive",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("49C1A7E1-0C79-4A89-A3D6-A37998FB86B0".Sha256()) },
                    
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44300/signin-oidc" },
                    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44300/signout-oidc",
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44300/signout-callback-oidc" },

                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "scope2" }
                },

                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "movie.web",

                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("xxx".Sha256()) },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,

                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc" },
     
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "movie.api" },
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser =  true
                },
            };
    }
```

In my console, I notice these information:

`code_challenge is missing` and `Request validation failed`

Where should I check on these?

If I set to `options.ResponseType = "code id_token";`, in my console, I will get `code_challenge is missing`

If I set to `options.ResponseType = "code";`, in my console, I will get `Invalid grant type for client: authorization_code`

I have troubleshoot `builder.AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients);` in the server and `ClientSecrets` in the server matches with client at `options.ClientSecret = xxx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get the "code_challenge is missing" error, its because your client does not include the following two headers:

```
&code_challenge=SD3BJSDKJ215KZAF...
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

In the client make sure this option is set to true:

```
options.UsePkce = true;
```

**PKCE** is the security enhancement to the authorization code flow. In IdentityServer v4.0x the **RequirePkce** option is now also set to true by default.

For the other problem, you should use

```
response_type = "code",
```

and in the IdentityServer client defintion you should use:

```
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
```

Or if you need multiple flows:

```
AllowedGrantTypes = 
{
    GrantType.AuthorizationCode,
    GrantType.Hybrid
},
```

But remember that PKCE is only supported for the Authorization code flow.

Comment: I have tried with   ` options.ResponseType = "code"; 
            options.UsePkce = true;` but when I load the login, it says `Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client
Invalid grant type for client` and in the console log `Invalid grant type for client: authorization_code`

Comment: I have tried your solution but I am still getting `Invalid grant type for client: authorization_code`. By the way, my clientid `movie.api` is set to `AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,`. So, my ResponseType is not `code id_token`?

Comment: Se my updated answer. Why do you need hybrid flow? Today authorization code flow and client credentials are the two flow you should try to aim for.

Comment: Are you happy with my answer or are there something missing? If not, please mark my answer as accepted.